# Add views outside a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, button, view

I have a problem while I am trying to create a simple ListView. 
Here is what I want : just an activity with 1 ListView with text inside (and buttons in the next steps) AND beside 1 (or more) button.

So in my XML I have a ListView, a TextView (the one inside the ListView's children and a button (the one I don't want inside my ListView).  When I lunch my app, i have every views of my activity in my listView... And i don't know where I have to manage that.

Here is my code : 
My activity :

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.MainListDecks);
AdapterDeck adpDeck;
ArrayList<Deck> myDecks = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){
    myDecks.add(new Deck("Deck " + i));
}

adpDeck = new AdapterDeck(this, 0, myDecks);
listView.setAdapter(adpDeck);
```

My adapter :

```
public AdapterDeck(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull 
ArrayList<Deck> decks) {
    super(context, resource, decks);
    this.decks = decks;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    }

    TextView listItemText = view.findViewById(R.id.MainDeckNom);
    listItemText.setText(decks.get(position).getNom())
    return view;
}
```

My XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Background"
    tools:context="activities.MainMenu">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/MainListDecks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MainDeckNom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
       android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result : [the result i got and i don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUepL.png)

Thanks for anyone who can help !

Cheers

Comment: How do you want your xml to be?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more what exactly you want ? also share the AdapterDeck class

Comment: Thanks for the replies. 
OK. 
I need an activity with a List and a Button. In my List i want a TextView (on every children of course). My List with all the names of my object and beside a button. At the moment when i'm trying to add a view in my activty, it seems it is added inside the list (or the List uses it if you prefere)

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers didn't work, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since more users have answered there (correctly), but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Comment: OK ! I get it 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They're not *in* your ListView, they're *above* it.

Your root layout is a RelativeLayout. RelativeLayout allows children to overlap. If you want a ListView with a button on the bottom right and (I'm assuming) some text on the bottom, you should be using a LinearLayout and a FrameLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="activities.MainMenu">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/MainListDecks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
     />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MainDeckNom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:text="Button" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
        />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I appreciate and it helped me ! But I need TextView in my list. With your solution, i have an empty ListView (or is there somethinh i don't get ?)
Without the FrameLayout, my ListView is using my TextView and Button to build itself (don't know how to define it exactly but this is how I understand it) I need my List to use the Text only; 

Thanks again !